# How to set up keyboard shortcut for bounding box viewport shading?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut

I want to set up key shortcuts for viewport shading modes. Problem is, I can’t figure out which keyword is the mode for *Bounding Box*.

I’ve got the other ones working, Rendered, Material, Textured, Solid, Wireframe all work.

I’ve tried the following: `BOUNDINGBOX`, `BOUNDING_BOX`, `BOUNDING`, `BOX`, `BOUNDS`, and several variations, none work.

Here are the user input values:
[image: screenshot]

Might you know which keyword works for “Bounding Box”?

Thanks.

Edit: In case it helps, the Context value is: `space_data.viewport_shade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go over to the 3D View Header, right click over the *Viewport Shading Mode* menu and choose the option *Online Python reference*.

That should take you to the Blender's [Official Python API Documentation](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77a_release/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.viewport_shade) where you can learn all about it.

There you will learn that the the `viewport_shade`property is an enum that accepts `[‘BOUNDBOX’, ‘WIREFRAME’, ‘SOLID’, ‘TEXTURED’, ‘MATERIAL’, ‘RENDERED’]`string values.

The one you are looking for would hence be `BOUNDBOX`.

[image: Viewport Shading]